# Error Code 7 - Out of memory problems on code that has ran without issue before, how can I solve this problem?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
Sub startupemail()

Set drivere = New WebDriver

drivere.Start "chrome"

drivere.Get "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox"

drivere.FindElementByName("identifier").SendKeys ("email@email.com")

drivere.FindElementByClass("VfPpkd-vQzf8d").Click

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")

Do Until InStr(1, drivere.Url, "challenge") > 0
    Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))
Loop

drivere.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys ("Mypassword")

drivere.FindElementByClass("VfPpkd-vQzf8d").Click

Do Until InStr(1, drivere.Url, "inbox") > 0
    Application.Wait (DateAdd("s", 1, Now))
Loop

Sheet2.Rows(1).Insert

Sheet2.Rows(3).Delete

Set headers = drivere.FindElementById(":46")

Set header2 = headers.FindElementByClass("bsU")

Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = header2.Text

If Sheet2.Cells(1, 1) > Sheet2.Cells(2, 1) Then

    Call mailrequest

Else: Call marketcheck

End If

End Sub
```

Error code 7 on 'Set header2 = headers.FindElementByClass("bsU")'
Code has worked multiple times before and suddenly started giving a code 7 anytime I tried running it. Please help